# how exactly does nginx/php-fpm process requests?

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

I'm currently testing a new nginx/php-fpm I have setup on a new VPS with 4GB of RAM:

from my php-fpm process pool config:

```
pm = static
pm.max_children = 10
```

I have a simple load.php script which has the following simulate a long running mysql query:

```
<?php
echo sleep(5);
echo "you see me after 5 seconds";
?>
```

I then throw some load at this script as follows:

```
ab -n 1000 -c 100 http://mydomain.com/load.php
```

When I tail the nginx access logs I see a trickle of requests at a time - rather than the high throughput I was expecting.

How exactly does the data flow from nginx to the php backend and back?

If I have 10 static child processes, will the php backend process 10 requests (at 5 seconds each) before then accepting another 10 requests? Certainly from sitting looking at the logs that would appear to be roughly the case - is this correct?

If this is the case and I'm running a php app that if fairly heavy at the DB end (and consequently at the php process time layer), should I simply be increasing the number of child processes to speed up how long it takes to concurrently handle requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pm.max_children` means you can only have that many php processes running at once. If they are all taking a long time, then you are tied up, and other incoming connections must wait. To resolve this, increase the size of the php-fpm pool to the maximum you can get away with given your resource constraints.

Comment: thanks for your answer Michael - I wanted to be sure what I suspected was correct - I will increase the conn pool as much as I can